# Windows server hardware id on Google Cloud

Tags: windows-server-2008, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, .net

I have a Windows Server 2008 VM running on Google Cloud. I have a mechanical design software installed on the VM so that I can access it while on the go. The software uses a hardware id (obtained from .NET framework but I do not know the method calls.) and my license key to authenticate me.
Everything was working for more than a year - this involved shutting down and restarting the VM many times.
However last week my authentication started to fail. When I contacted the support team, they told me that the authentication failed because the software was sending a different hardware id than present in their db. I got the hardware id updated from support team to resolve the issue.
Now I would like to know why this happened and how to avoid this problem in future

Comment: Ask the software support how to avoid this failure in the future, including how this hardware ID thing works. Such an algorithm isn't really standardized, particularly if they want to obfuscate the exact details.

Comment: The support team could / did not help. I am guessing they get hardware id from some combination of following calls GetProcessorId()
GetVolumeSerial()
GetMotherBoardID()
GetMACAddress() 
But why would the response to any of these calls will change over time?

Answer (score 0):

**To avoid such situations** you should check Licence Agreements of any licensed software you want to use in cloud to check if you have permissions to do it. Hardware ID of your VM instance could be changed due to infrastructure maintenance or/and upgrades.

Google provides [Sole-tenant nodes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/nodes/sole-tenant-nodes) as a part of Google Cloud, they could be useful in case of using some licensed software. Please have a look at the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/nodes/sole-tenant-nodes):

> VMs running on sole-tenant nodes can use the same Compute Engine features as other VMs, including transparent scheduling and block storage, but with an added layer of hardware isolation. To give you full control over the VMs on the physical server, **each sole-tenant node maintains a one-to-one mapping to the physical server that is backing the node**.

and

> Sole-tenant nodes can help you meet dedicated hardware requirements for [bring your own license (BYOL)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/nodes/bringing-your-own-licenses) scenarios that require per-core or per-processor licenses. When you use sole-tenant nodes, you have some visibility into the underlying hardware, which lets you track core and processor usage. To track this usage, Compute Engine reports the ID of the physical server on which a VM is scheduled. Then, by using [Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs), you can [view the historical server usage of a VM](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/nodes/determining-server-usage). To optimize the use of the host hardware, you can [overcommit sole-tenant VM CPUs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/nodes/overcommitting-cpus-sole-tenant-vms).

but there are some [restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/nodes/sole-tenant-nodes#restrictions) you should keep in mind.

In addition, while using [Sole-tenant nodes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/nodes/sole-tenant-nodes) you can have more restrictive [Maintenance policies](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/nodes/sole-tenant-nodes#maintenance_policies) that could help you to stay within the Licence Agreement.